# Добавленные ajax'ом элементы не реагируют на кнопки экшенов

Tags: jquery, ajax

Всем привет. Делаю круд на jquery/ajax/laravel. Записи добавляются, редактируются, удаляются. Но, проблема в том, если добавить новый элемент путем добавления, он скриптом аппендится в таблицу с необходимы айди в атрибутах, но после добавления(без перезагрузки страницы) кнопки экшенов править\удалить - НЕ АКТИВНЫ.
Помогите выяснить причину и способы решения. Спасибо.

Пример работы на тесте тут - goo.gl/moxqSl 
Ссылка на файл js - goo.gl/okMkmW

P.S. инфа в базу записывается нормально.

Comment: навешивайте события кликов на родителя например. `$('parent').on('click', 'child_button', function(){});

Comment: Я сделал $('td').on('click','button.edit_cat', function(){  - однако событие все равно не отрабатывает на свежедобавленном элементе. На старых событие работает нормально.

Comment: Если у вас добавляется скриптом строка - td - то надо навешивать на тот контейнер который есть всегда - на таблицу например, в которую будете вставлять строки

Comment: Благодарю! Получилось!